# How to pronounce "de Morgan" in "de Morgan's Law" or "Augustus de Morgan" in British English?

Tags: etymology

How to pronounce "de Morgan" in "de Morgan's Law" or "[Augustus de Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus_De_Morgan)" in British English? As you may know, "de Morgan" occurs frequently in mathematics and so it's useful to know the determined pronunciation for it.

Any native British know that? If you know, please use the [International Phonetic Alphabet for English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English) to show how to read it. Furthermore, it's better to give a reference to the accurate sound provided.

By the way, I learn that someone reads it as [də ˈmɔ(r)gən] or [deɪ ˈmɔ(r)gən] or [dɪ ˈmɔ(r)gən], but it's not sure whether the sound "də" or "deɪ" or "di" for *de* is right or not.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141070/discussion-on-question-by-m-logic-how-to-pronounce-de-morgan-in-de-morgans).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: People pronounce *de Morgan* as either /də ˈmɔ(r)gən/ or /dɪ ˈmɔ(r)gən/.

There is no question about the *Morgan* part; the only way to pronounce this name is /ˈmɔrgən/ or /ˈmɔgən/, depending on whether you have a rhotic accent or not.

So the problematic part is the *de*.
One thing you can do to figure out the pronunciation is to look at how *de* is pronounced in other names in English. For example, there is Thomas de Quincey, whose [Wikipedia artlcle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_De_Quincey) gives the pronunciation /də ˈkwɪnsi/. Another example is Hernando de Soto, where [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hernando_de_Soto) says the English pronunciation is /də ˈsoʊtoʊ/, while the Spanish pronunciation is  /ðe ˈsoto/.

Another thing you can do is listen to Youglish pronunciations of *de Morgan's law* on [Youglish](https://youglish.com/pronounce/de%20morgan%27s%20law/english?), which compiles Youtube videos with those words. Most of them use /də/, while a singificant fraction (maybe around a third) use /dɪ/. In fully reduced vowels, /ə/ and /ɪ/ are interchangeable for a large number of native English speakers, so I would say  thatboth pronunciations are correct.

Many English speakers use /deɪ/ for Spanish or Italian names that start with *de*, like *de Soto*, as this phoneme is closer to the one in Spanish or Italian. So I would say that pronouncing *de Morgan* as /deɪ/ is a mistake, albeit an understandable one.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of the word "Detour" began as "de-Tour" I believe from the French, with the accent on the "Tour" rather than the "de". American "Detour" has the accent rather clumsily on the "De". I hear it pronounced the old way in old radio shows. In analysis classes we always pronounced de Morgan the old way; as "dee Morgan" or "dae Morgan", I have no schwa key here to be more precise. The accent is again on the "de" rather than the "Morgan".

Comment: Needs reference.